# How to show that the Lie derivative $L_{Y}Z$ is equivalent to the Lie bracket $[Y, Z]$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, vector-fields, lie-derivative

How can you show that, if $Y,Z \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $Y$ is complete, then: $$L_{Y}Z=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\phi^{-1}_{t*}(Z)\bigg\rvert_{t=0}\equiv[Y, Z]$$

Where $\phi_{t}$ is in the one parameter group generated by $Y$. I know it should be something related to using charts to get it "down" to $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I don't see how to do that with $\phi^{-1}_{t*}$.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Kobayashi and Nomizu - Foundations of Differential Geometry vol. 1?

Comment: No Gibbs, I haven't. I'm reading the book by David Bleecker "gauge theory and variational principles". I recall having seen the Lie derivative in a Relativity course, but the definition was not very formal (we skipped the ideas of charts, tangent space, etc. And only worked in local coordinates).

Comment: I don't see why you need $Y$ complete; you only the flow to be locally defined at each point.

Comment: @SalvadorVillarreal I studied the proof on that book. I try to rewrite it as clearly as possible as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We assume to be on a smooth manifold $M$. Let $X,Y$ be two vector fields on $M$ and $\varphi_t$ be the one-parameter group generated by $X$. Our claim is
$$[X,Y]_p = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{(\varphi_{-t})_{*|\varphi_t(p)}Y_{\varphi_t(p)}-Y_p}{t},$$
so essentially you want to show that the vectors on both sides are equal. Two vectors at $p$ coincide when the directional derivatives of each smooth function defined around $p$ with respect to both of them are equal. So take a function $f$ defined around $p$ and calculate 
$$((\varphi_{-t})_{*|\varphi_t(p)}Y_{\varphi_t(p)}-Y_p)f,$$
where here $t$ is small enough that $\varphi_t(p)$ sits in the same chart as $p$ - you can assume this because you will take the limit $t \to 0^+$. You have
$$
((\varphi_{-t})_{*|\varphi_t(p)}Y_{\varphi_t(p)}-Y_p)f = Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}(f\circ \varphi_{-t})-Y_pf,
$$
so one first step is to write $f \circ \varphi_{-t}$ in a simpler way. Consider the function $F(t,\cdot):= f\circ \varphi_{-t}-f$. You can see that $F(0,p)=0$ and a result from analysis tells you that there exists a function $g=g(t,q)$ such that $f \circ \varphi_{-t} - f = tg$. Such a function is defined as
$$g(t,p) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(st,p)\,ds.$$
Also, 
$$g = \frac{f\circ \varphi_{-t} - f}{t}$$
so when $t \to 0^+$ you get $g(0,p) = -X_pf$. All of this is good because now $f\circ \varphi_{-t} = f+tg$ and then
\begin{align}
Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}(f\circ \varphi_{-t}) -Y_pf&= Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}(f+tg) -Y_pf\\
& = Y_{\varphi_t(p)}f-Y_pf+tY_{\varphi_t(p)}g.
\end{align}
Divide by $t$:
\begin{align}
\frac{Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}(f\circ \varphi_{-t})-Y_pf}{t}&=\frac{Y_{\varphi_t(p)}f-Y_pf+tY_{\varphi_t(p)}g}{t} \\
& = \frac{Y_{\varphi_t(p)}f-Y_pf}{t}+Y_{\varphi_t(p)}g.
\end{align}
Now as $t \to 0^+$ the first term goes to $X_p(Yf)$, whereas the second one goes to $-Y_p(Xf)$, hence your limit is
$$X_p(Yf)-Y_p(Xf) = [X,Y]_pf$$
which shows the claim.

Comment: Why do you use $(\phi_{-t})_{*}$? I thought $\phi_{t*}^{-1}=(\phi_{t*})^{-1}$ rather than $(\phi_{t}^{-1})_{*}=(\phi_{-t})_{*}$. Are these two the same?

Comment: The inverse of $\varphi_t$ is $\varphi_{-t}$, because $\varphi_{t+s} = \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's a one parameter group and it's linear in the "t" parameter. But I believe that the inverse is taken on the whole thing, the inverse of $\phi_{t*}$ as an operator acting on the tangent bundle $TM$ of $M$. What you're saying is that the inverse is taken on $\phi_{t}$, an operator acting on $M$.

Comment: But the derivative of the inverse *is* the inverse of the derivative, by the chain rule. Nevertheless, it really is clearest to work with $(\phi_{-t})_*$. :)

Comment: I think you got the signs mixed up in a few places along your answer (which I find good and helpful, BTW).

Comment: @AmitaiYuval you are right, thank you for noticing.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I edited the answer, now it looks fine to me. Please, let me know if you see any mistake.

Comment: Ah! I get it now, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, $Gibbs, it seems that it's fine now.

Comment: How do you show that $Y_{\varphi_t (p)} (g) \to - Y_p (X(f))$ as $t \to 0$ given that $\varphi_0 (p) = p$ and $g(0,p) = - X_p (f)$ i.e. $g(0, \cdot) = - X(f)\ $?

Comment: There seems to be some handwaving at the end.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Apply $\dfrac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \phi_{-t*}Z$ to a smooth function $f$ and use $Yf = \dfrac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} f\circ\phi_t$. The tricky part will be differentiating $Z_{\phi_t(p)}(f\circ\phi_{-t})$; perhaps the easier way to do this is to think about differentiating $Z_{\phi_s(p)}(f\circ\phi_{-t})$ and then applying the chain rule.

*Comment*: No need to do anything in charts.